# Android Navigation Drawer - Hide/Show list item

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, show-hide

I have one class that define the itens list of a navigation drawer, and I wish to hide or show some of them based on specific events.

Below, is the class that defines the list of itens:

```
public class Config {

  public static List<NavItem> configuration() {

    List<NavItem> i = new ArrayList<NavItem>();

    //DONT MODIFY ABOVE THIS LINE
    i.add(new NavItem("Item01", R.drawable.ic_action_favorite, NavItem.SECTION));
    i.add(new NavItem("Item02", R.drawable.ic_details, NavItem.ITEM, HomeFragment.class, null));
    i.add(new NavItem("Item03", R.drawable.ic_vistoria_blue, NavItem.ITEM, VistoriaActivity.class));

    i.add(new NavItem("Item04", R.drawable.ic_details, NavItem.ITEM, BotaoPanicoFragment.class, null));
    i.add(new NavItem("Item05", R.drawable.ic_details, NavItem.ITEM, BotoeiraFragment.class, null));

    i.add(new NavItem("Item06", R.drawable.ic_action_settings, NavItem.SECTION));
    i.add(new NavItem("Item07", R.drawable.ic_action_favorite, NavItem.EXTRA, SyncImportFragment.class, null));

    //DONT MODIFY BELOW THIS LINE

    return i;
  }
}
```

And in my fragment, I call the below to get the drawer list:

```
private List<NavItem> getConfiguration(){
    if (null == mConfiguration){
        mConfiguration = Config.configuration();

        boolean newDrawer = getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.newdrawer);

        if (newDrawer == true){
            mConfiguration.add(0, new NavItem("Header", NavItem.TOP));
        }
    }

    return mConfiguration;
}
```

Could someone help me to show at begin only item01, item02, and item03. And after, the others?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a sublist of the prepared list, implementing this at the same spot you already modify the returned list if the drawer is new:

```
if (newDrawer == true){
    mConfiguration = mConfiguration.sublist(0, 2);
    mConfiguration.add(0, new NavItem("Header", NavItem.TOP));
} else {
    //No changes needed, use direct result of configuration()
}
```

I assume that getConfiguration() is called again later, then entering the false branch, resulting in returning the list as it is generated in configuration().

Comment: I got you. So, I need to find a way to get access to mConfiguration in order to change the sublist.

Comment: It should be enough to call getConfiguration() again after the boolean newDrawer will return false.